# Are Devaronians fire proof?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the Mandalorian Episode 6 "The Prisoner" Mando gets into a fight with Burg the Devaronian.  Mando uses his arm mounted flame thrower [(ZX miniature flame projector?)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/ZX_miniature_flame_projector/Legends), that has worked on others in the past including armored stormtroopers, on Burg's face to no effect.
In my research I found that Devoronians have two livers that remove toxins and carcinogens, they use sulfur as a stimulant, and the males look like 'devils'.  All these things are associated with fire but there is no direct connection I could find. Are Devoronians shown to be immune to fire in other canon sources or is this to show that Burg is a [Giant Mook](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GiantMook) or [The Brute](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheBrute)? (caution TV tropes)

Answer (score 1):

Most of what we know of Devaronians comes from Star Wars Legends.  It is possible that this is just part of Devaronian biology in canon.